# Python- Print Specific Object List Attribute

Tags: python, oop

How do I print a specific object attribute from a list of objects. I was thinking I could provide the specific list index but I get the following error when I try that: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'grade'`

```
class tests():

    def __init__(self,grade):
         self.grade = grade


test_list = []

for x in range(1,6):
    test_object = tests(x)
    test_list.append(test_object)


print (test_list[1].grade)
```

Comment: **Indentation matters.** Please fix your example code.  Right away, though, I notice you're wrapping your list in a list in the `for` loop..

Comment: `for x in [test_list]:` needs to be `for x in test_list:` for starters. But, uh, why are you iterating through it in the first place? you can sort using sorted just fine if that is your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You have some bugs here.

```
class tests():

    def __init__(self,grade):
         self.grade = grade


test_list = []

for x in range(1,6):
    test_object = tests(x)
    test_list.append(test_object)

list_a = [5,3,2,1,4]

# THIS LINE BELOW IS THE PROBLEM    
for x in [test_list]:
    # in this line below X = test_list and indeed test_list.grade doesn't make sense.
    test_list.append(sorted(x.grade,key=list_a.index))


print (test_list[1].grade)
```

Comment: this doesnt really answer his question (who knows what that question actually is... although maybe it helps him understand his issue)

Comment: Well the problem is that the question isn't actually real. `test_list[1].grade` will return the value of `grade` at index `1`. The problem is earlier where they just have a bug.